# how to use base2 in math

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, binary

I have a list of base2 values (5 digits each) :

```
[10000, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000, 11001, 11010, 11011, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111]
```

Is there a way to do math with them in base2? For Example, `10001 + 1110 = 11111`

And `10000 - 1 = 1111`.

EDIT : I only care about addition and subtraction.

Comment: math is always done in base 2. Computers don't understand anything besides 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 4):

By default, any number you write is in base 10. Thus when you typed `10000`, you actually wrote the number *ten thousands*.

### Inputing a number in binary

If you want to specify that you are writing a number in binary, then use the `0b` prefix.

```
>>> 0b10000
16
```

If for any reason you cannot update your code to add the above prefix, you can use this helper function to convert a decimal notation to its binary value.

```
def decimal_notation_to_binary(x):
    return int(str(x), 2)
```

Example:

```
>>> decimal_notation_to_binary(10000)
16
```

### Getting the binary representation of a number

Alternatively, if what you want is the binary representation of a number, use the `bin` builtin function.

```
>>> bin(42)
'0b101010'
```

### Arithmetic

As for arithmetic, the difference between a binary number and a decimal number is only the way Python writes it on your screen, in memory all integers are stored as binary. This means you can do arithmetic with numbers given in binary the same way you would for any number.

```
>>> 0b10000 + 0b1000
24
```

As a matter of fact, as proof that the base in which you input a number is irrelevant, you can even add a binary, a decimal and an hexadecimal number.

```
>>> 0b100 + 0x1f + 7
42
```

Answer (score 1):

**@Naji**, have a look at the below code examples.

> You can use **int()** and **bin()** functions multiple times to satisfy your goal.

```
a = 10000
b = 1

# Base 2 addition
result1 = (bin( int(str(a), 2) - int(str(b), 2) )[2:] # 1111

# Base 2 subtraction
result2 = bin( int(str(a), 2) + int(str(b), 2) )[2:]  # 10001
```

#### » A try on Python's interactive console

```
>>> # Base 2 subtraction & addition 
...
>>> a = 10000
>>> b = 1
>>>
>>> result = bin( int(str(a), 2) - int(str(b), 2) )
>>> result
'0b1111'
>>>
>>> result = bin( int(str(a), 2) + int(str(b), 2) )
>>> result
'0b10001'
>>>
>>> result = bin( int(str(a), 2) - int(str(b), 2) )[2:]
>>> result
'1111'
>>>
>>> result = bin( int(str(a), 2) + int(str(b), 2) )[2:]
>>> result
'10001'
>>>
```

Let's try to add all the binary numbers that you have specified in the problem.

```
>>> binaries = [10000, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000, 11001, 11010, 11011, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111]
>>>
>>> decimals = [int(str(binary), 2) for binary in binaries]
>>> decimals
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
>>>
>>> sum(decimals)
376
>>>
>>> bin(sum(decimals))
'0b101111000'
>>>
>>> bin(sum(decimals))[2:]
'101111000'
>>>
```

Finally, we can design our own function that will result exact binay string (i.e. without `0b` prepended as in `0b1111`) after addition or subtraction.

```
# ********* BASE2 ADDITION ***************
def base2_addition(a, b):
    try:
        int_a = int(str(a), 2) 
        int_b = int(str(b), 2) 

        return bin(int_a + int_b)[2:] 
    except:
        print ("Invalid input provided (Expected 2 binary strings/numbers with 0s and 1s")
        return None

print base2_addition('10000', '1')   # 10001
print base2_addition('10001', '011') # 10100

# ********* BASE2 SUBTRACTION **************
def base2_subtraction(a, b):
    try:
        int_a = int(str(a), 2) 
        int_b = int(str(b), 2) 

        return bin(int_a - int_b)[2:] 
    except:
        print ("Invalid input provided (Expected 2 binary strings/numbers with 0s and 1s")
        return None

print(base2_subtraction('10100', '101')) # 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to int, do the operation, then convert back to binary.
For instance:

print(bin(int('1001', base=2) + int('1011', base=2))[2:])

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers you are working with are base 10 representations. You can prefix with `0b` to make it base 2 ex `0b10001 + 0b1110` which equals `31` (`0b11111`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to treat these `int` numbers as binary numbers you will first need to convert them to binary:

```
In []:
lst = [10000, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000, 11001, 11010, 11011, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111]
blst = [int(str(n), 2) for n in lst]
print(blst)

Out[]:
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

The default for `int`s is to print base 10 so `0b10000` is `16` in base 10. 
Even when using binary literals, e.g.:

```
In []:
[0b10000, 0b10001, 0b10010, 0b10011, 0b10100, 0b10101]

Out[]:
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

You can print them as binary with:

```
In []:
print(' '.join(format(n, 'b') for n in blst))

Out[]:
10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101 11110 11111
```

You can add and delete these values and as long as you print them out in binary it will be as you expect, e.g. to subtract `0b1` from all of them:

```
In []:
print(' '.join(format(n - 0b1, 'b') for n in blst))

Out[]:
1111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101 11110
```

And adding `0b1110`:

```
In []:
print(' '.join(format(n + 0b1110, 'b') for n in blst))

Out[]:
11110 11111 100000 100001 100010 100011 100100 100101 100110 100111 101000 101001 101010 101011 101100 101101
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `int` docstring, it takes `int` or `long` datatype

```
Docstring:
int(x=0) -> int or long
int(x, base=10) -> int or long
```

And `bin` takes `str`:

```
Docstring:
bin(number) -> string
```

Since your list is of `base10` instead of `base2`, it's not the prettiest nor the fastest, I would convert your list of `base10` into `base2` type through casting and do the math.
Since you mentioned you only cared about the subtraction or addition, I added the variable X to control your subtraction or addition.

**NOTE**: I assume the variable X here takes `base2` formatted `string` or `int`, so it will be no problem for you to give an `X = '1000'` or `X = 1000` value. It throws `ValueError` exception if you input any number that is more or equal to 2, for example: `X = 1112` or `X = 16`

```
nums = [10000, 10001, 10010, 10011, 10100, 10101, 10110, 10111, 11000, 11001, 11010, 11011, 11100, 11101, 11110, 11111]    
nums_string = [str(num) for num in nums]

X = 1
nums_sum = [bin(int(num, base=2) + int(str(X), base=2)) for num in nums_string]
nums_sum

['0b10001',
 '0b10010',
 '0b10011',
 '0b10100',
 '0b10101',
 '0b10110',
 '0b10111',
 '0b11000',
 '0b11001',
 '0b11010',
 '0b11011',
 '0b11100',
 '0b11101',
 '0b11110',
 '0b11111',
 '0b100000']

X = -1
nums_sum = [bin(int(num, base=2) + int(str(X), base=2)) for num in nums_string]
nums_sum
['0b1111',
 '0b10000',
 '0b10001',
 '0b10010',
 '0b10011',
 '0b10100',
 '0b10101',
 '0b10110',
 '0b10111',
 '0b11000',
 '0b11001',
 '0b11010',
 '0b11011',
 '0b11100',
 '0b11101',
 '0b11110']

X = -10000
nums_sum = [bin(int(num, base=2) + int(str(X), base=2)) for num in nums_string]
nums_sum
['0b0',
 '0b1',
 '0b10',
 '0b11',
 '0b100',
 '0b101',
 '0b110',
 '0b111',
 '0b1000',
 '0b1001',
 '0b1010',
 '0b1011',
 '0b1100',
 '0b1101',
 '0b1110',
 '0b1111']

X = '-10000'
nums_sum = [bin(int(num, base=2) + int(str(X), base=2)) for num in nums_string]
nums_sum
['0b0',
 '0b1',
 '0b10',
 '0b11',
 '0b100',
 '0b101',
 '0b110',
 '0b111',
 '0b1000',
 '0b1001',
 '0b1010',
 '0b1011',
 '0b1100',
 '0b1101',
 '0b1110',
 '0b1111']

X = '-11111'
nums_sum = [bin(int(num, base=2) + int(str(X), base=2)) for num in nums_string]
nums_sum
'-0b1111',
'-0b1110',
'-0b1101',
'-0b1100',
'-0b1011',
'-0b1010',
'-0b1001',
'-0b1000',
'-0b111',
'-0b110',
'-0b101',
'-0b100',
'-0b11',
'-0b10',
'-0b1',
'0b0']
```

Depending on the operations that you want to automate, the code to accomplish varies.